# Need help for conditioning in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am developing Online Quiz Module.
So i have define 2 types of questions.

1. Multiple Choice Single Option(Radio Button)
2. Multiple Choice Multiple Option(Checkbox)
3. Other Naswer(Textbox)

I have used Nested Repeater.The first repeater bind the Question.
And the child repeater bind the Options available for the Questions.

So what i want is i want to check the COndition,

Like if my QuestionType is MS(Multiple Choice Single Option) the i will bind the 4 options with Radio Buttons.

If its MM(Multiple Choice Multiple Option) then i will bind Options with Checkbox.

So how can i check such condition and code in the aspx file.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to do it:

### Output

[image]

### ASPX

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater" DataSourceID="ods" 
        onitemdatabound="repeater_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("QuestionText") %>' runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel">
            </asp:Panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetQuestions" 
        TypeName="WebApplication1.Questions.QuestionsContext">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

### Code behind

```
    protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var q = e.Item.DataItem as Question;

        if (q == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        var panel = e.Item.FindControl("panel");

        if (q.MultipleAnswers)
        {
            var checks = new CheckBoxList { DataSource = q.Answers, DataTextField = "AnswerText", DataValueField = "ID" };
            checks.DataBind();

            panel.Controls.Add(checks);
        }
        else
        {
            var radios = new RadioButtonList { DataSource = q.Answers, DataTextField = "AnswerText", DataValueField = "ID" };
            radios.DataBind();

            panel.Controls.Add(radios);
        }
    }
```

### Data component

This is just for testing, replace it with your data source

```
public class QuestionsContext
{
    public IEnumerable<Question> GetQuestions()
    {
        var q = Builder<Question>.CreateListOfSize(5).Build().ToList();
        q.ForEach(x =>
        {
            x.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            x.Answers = Builder<Answer>.CreateListOfSize(4)
                .All().With(y => y.Question, x)
                .Build().ToList();
        });

        return q;
    }
}
```

### Model

```
public class Answer
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
}
public class Question
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public bool MultipleAnswers { get; set; }

    public Question()
    {
        this.Answers = Enumerable.Empty<Answer>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton..It worked.but now how will be i able to check which radio button or which checkbox the user checked for perticular question on the server side???